# Error with updating a legend's style item in pycharm

Tags: arcpy, legend, pycharm, style-manager

I am trying to update an item in the legend with a style item, this is the code:

```
#Add Legend 
legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "LEGEND_ELEMENT", "Legend") [0]
legendLayers = legend.listLegendItemLayers()

#Using Style Manager to edit Legend
styleItem = arcpy.mapping.ListStyleItems("C:\\Users\\Windows\\Desktop\\test\\style manager\\noise(dBA).style", "Legend Items", "noise(dBA)")
legend.update(insertLayer, styleItem)
```

but I keep receiving the following error message:

```
legend.update(insertLayer, styleItem)
AttributeError: 'LegendElement' object has no attribute 'update'
```

I am a complete newbie with PyCharm and coding!

Comment: I doubt the issue is with pycharm. Does this work in an environment outside of pycharm?

Comment: I'm only working within pycharm, I ended up changing my code to the following and it worked: legend.updateItem(lyr, styleItem)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused on the last line legend.update as there is no update method or property for the LegendElement. Have a look at the LegendElement example 3 in the help.

Another issue. There is a space on line 1 of your code, between the list and the index. It should read

```
legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "LEGEND_ELEMENT", "Legend")[0]
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked! for some reason, I now have a new issue! I am trying to update a different layer in the legend with a different style item, but I am receiving this error: ValueError: <geoprocessing Style Item object object  at 0x5921880>